# How to add an arrow between two side by side figures?

Tags: floats, arrows, nodes

I want to add an arrow between these two side-by-side figures. Both of them would have their own captions. I made these figures in Geogebra and will import the figure using `\includegraphics`. I am new to Latex, sorry for such a basic question.
[image: arrow between these tow arrows]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb, mathrsfs,pgf,tikz,pgfplots,enumitem,gensymb,fancyhdr, mathtools}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{que}{Question}
\numberwithin{equation}{que}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \hspace{1.15cm}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=6cm]{fig1crop.png} 
        \caption{Caption1}
        \label{fig:sub1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \hspace{1.15cm}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=6cm]{fig2crop.png}
        \caption{Caption 2}
        \label{fig:sub2}
        \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
    \label{fig:image2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimum code from `\documentclass{...` to `\end{document}`. The class used and preamble are important for a solution that will work for you.

Comment: @SimonDispa I added it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my barn of old solution I found the following example. It may help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, belowskip=2ex]{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize, valign=m]{example-image-a}
        \caption{SICAPI}
        \label{fig.SICAPI}
    \end{subfigure}
\qquad\tikz[baseline=-\baselineskip]\draw[ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);\qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize, valign=m]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Painel de operação}
    \label{fig.painel_sicapi}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Planta Piloto SICAPI}
    \label{fig.sicapi}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I got it.

Comment: @Globos, you are welcome!

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again. How can i make the arrow a little bit more thick and long? I don't know tikz

Comment: @Globos, change options of command `\draw`. For example `\draw[line width=4mm,-{Triangle[length=6mm, width=8mm]}] (0,0) -- ++ (2,0);`. However, at arrow legs you should take a care, that widths of bot images and arrows will be less than `\textwidth`! For details  about `tikz` see package documentation.